# regex: get match and remaining string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to run a regular expression against a string and let me get both the match and the remaining string.

the above is to be able to implement the following UI pattern:

[image]

as you can see in the image I need to separate the match from the rest of the string to be able to apply some style or any other process separately.

```js
/**
 * INPUT 
 * 
 * input: 'las vegas'
 * pattern: 'las'
 *
 *
 * EXPECTED OUTPUT
 * 
 * match: 'las'
 * remaining: 'vegas'
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the match then replace the match with nothing in the string, and return both results.

```js
function matchR(str, regex){
    // get the match
    var _match = str.match(regex);
    
    // return the first match index, and the remaining string
    return {match:_match[0], remaining:str.replace(_match, "")};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that takes the user input and an array of strings to match as as parameters, and returns an array of arrays:

```js
const strings = [
  'Las Cruces',
  'Las Vegas',
  'Los Altos',
  'Los Gatos',
];

function getMatchAndRemaining(input, strings) {
  let escaped = input.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  let regex = new RegExp('^(' + escaped + ')(.*)$', 'i');
  return strings.map(str => {
    return (str.match(regex) || [str, '', str]).slice(1);
  });  
}

//tests:
['l', 'las', 'los', 'x'].forEach(input => {
  let matches = getMatchAndRemaining(input, strings);
  console.log(input, '=>', matches);
});
```

Some notes:

- you need to escape the user input before creating the regex, some chars have special meaning
- if there is no match, the before part is empty, and the remaining part contains the full string
- you could add an additional parameter to the function with style or class to add to the before part, in which case you would return a string instead of an array of [before, remaining]